# .js File in scripts folder "undefined" MVC5 C#

Tags: c#, javascript

I am not sure at all what I am doing with this... I have a javascript file in my scripts folder called popCalendar2.js which I want to run on a button click...

```
<input type="button" name="endDTPick" value="..." style="cursor:pointer;" class="bodyText" onmouseover="this.style.color='orangered';" onmouseout="this.style.color='black';" onclick="popCalendar2('7/17/2014', '7/22/2014', 'm/d/yyyy');">
```

When I run the view that I want the calendar to display on and click the Button in my console (ctrl/shift/I) I get the error... PopCalendar2 is undefined

I am going to run through this tutorial and see if it helps my understanding: "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/638674/Full-calendar-A-complete-web-diary-system-for-jQue"

But if anybody knows that I just need to add a @Script.render or anything simple like that it would be helpful :) Also, do I need to have some other scripts like JQuery-min or is that completely based upon what my popCalendar2.js file is trying to do?

Comment: Did you include the JavaScript file in your view/layout?

Comment: I think I did, I put this into my <head> tag in my _Layout.cshtml file  and put a break point there to make sure it is running... `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/popCalendar2.js")"></script>`

Comment: Also: `@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
    ViewBag.Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}` on top of my view

Comment: Open the JavaScript debug console (F12) and see if the variable PopCalendar2 exists in the global scope. Was there any initialization that needs to be done with it?

Comment: In mvc5 you dont need to Url.Content your script files, shave some extra bytes off the cshtml and easier on the eyes.

Comment: I see PopCalendar2 under Elements in a HTML tag and I also see it under Sources in the localhost/scripts folder and I don't believe there needs to need any initialization (I am trying to replicate someones old code)

Comment: So just <script src="("~/Scripts/popCalendar2.js")"></script> works the same? @Rodrigo

Comment: And then wouldnt there be a HTML Helper for that as well? to cut out the tags?

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/popCalendar2.js"></script>  actually.

Comment: @krillgar Thanks for mentioning the initialization, after lookin it over many times, I finally realized I did need to just didnt need to pass anything to it! :D Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I just needed to add.. =)

```
onload="init()"
```

or

```
<body onload="init();"></body>
```